# How to display what user selected from a list?

Tags: javascript, ajax

After the user chooses an artist and the title,when the 'display' button is clicked, I want to show a table with all the information(title,artist,country,company,year,price)for that artist and title.But my code just run just the first option.How can i fix it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>
<form id="form1">
<select name="Artist">
<option value="Artist"> Choose an Artist </option>
<option value="1"> Bob Dylan </option>
<option value="2">Bonnie Tyler  </option>
<option value="3"> Dolly Parton </option>
</select>
<select name="Title">
<option value="-Title"> -Choose the title </option>
<option value="a"> Empire Burlesque </option>
<option value="b"> Hide your heart </option>
<option value="c"> Greatest Hits </option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Display</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th><th>Country</th><th>Company</th><th>Price</th>Year</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +  x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +  x[i].getElementsByTagName("COUNTRY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +  x[i].getElementsByTagName("COMPANY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
<CATALOG>
<CD>
<TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1988</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1982</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
<YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Eros</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1997</YEAR>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: Where is your code? Oh, and... Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are no algorithm to compare xml value with selected option.
2. select options have meaningless values.

> check my plunk example. http://embed.plnkr.co/qcNQWXa7fmZ4ry5nRIlz/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  table,th,td {
    border : 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  th,td {
    padding: 5px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1">
    <select name="Artist" id="cd_artist">
      <option value="Artist"> Choose an Artist </option>
      <option value="Bob Dylan">Bob Dylan</option>
      <option value="Bonnie Tyler">Bonnie Tyler</option>
      <option value="Dolly Parton">Dolly Parton</option>
    </select>
    <select name="Title" id="cd_title">
      <option value="-Title"> -Choose the title </option>
      <option value="Empire Burlesque">Empire Burlesque</option>
      <option value="Hide your heart">Hide your heart</option>
      <option value="Greatest Hits">Greatest Hits</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Display</button>
  <br><br>
  <table id="demo"></table>
  
  <script>
    function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          myFunction(this);
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
    
    function myFunction(xml) {
      var artistObj = document.getElementById('cd_artist');
      var titleObj = document.getElementById('cd_title');
      var selectedArtist = artistObj.options[artistObj.selectedIndex].value;
      var selectedTitle = titleObj.options[titleObj.selectedIndex].value;
      
      var i;
      var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
      var tableHeader = "<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th><th>Country</th><th>Company</th><th>Price</th><th>Year</th></tr>";
      var tableBody = "";
      var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");

      for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
        var xmlArtist = x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var xmlTitle = x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var xmlCountry = x[i].getElementsByTagName("COUNTRY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var xmlCompany = x[i].getElementsByTagName("COMPANY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var xmlPrice = x[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var xmlYear = x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        
        if(selectedArtist == xmlArtist && selectedTitle == xmlTitle) {
          tableBody = "<tr><td>" + xmlArtist + "</td><td>" + xmlTitle + "</td><td>" + xmlCountry + 
                  "</td><td>" + xmlCompany + "</td><td>" + xmlPrice + "</td><td>" + xmlYear + "</td></tr>";
          break;        
        } else {
          tableBody = "<tr><td colspan='6' align='center'>Not Found</td></tr>"
        }
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = tableHeader + tableBody;

    }
    
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Smith Lee .How can i download the displayed table as a pdf file?

Comment: may i ask you for an exercise similar to this, please ?